# How to create dynamic char array in llvmlite?

Tags: python, c, llvm, llvmlite

Based on llvmlite docs I can create static array like in a code snippet bellow.

```
ir.Constant(ir.ArrayType(ir.ArrayType(i8, STR_SIZE), ARR_SIZE), elements)
```

But can I create dynamic array in llvmlite or convert variable above to *i8.as_pointer().as_pointer()* type?

Comment: `char**` is a pointer type, not an array type, and yes, you can create pointer types in LLVM.

Comment: @sepp2k, is it possible to convert ArrayType variable to Pointer Type variable?

Comment: You can turn a pointer to a T array into a pointer to T using `getelementptr`. You can't get a pointer into an array that is stored directly in a register because registers don't have addresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`char**` isn't an array, it's a pointer to pointer to `char`. C programs often use such a pointer and pretend that the type pointed to is something else.

LLVM lets you do the same, and in a fairly similar way. If you look closely at the [getelementptr](https://llvm.org/docs/GetElementPtr.html) instruction, you'll notice that it takes both a pointer argument and a type argument. The type is the type pointed to. If you pass gep an array type, a pointer and an index, it pretends that the pointer points to that type and returns a pointer to an array entry with the specified index, which you can then [load](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1LoadInst.html) and treat as a Value.

Comment: It is also possible to use extern C function like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65544768/15330019).